# How do I cool my water bottle immediately for an emergency use?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, home-experiment, heat

What are the chemicals I can use to cool my water-bottle at once if I'm stranded in a desert and I have only chemicals to cool water?

*(I'm keeping those chemicals outside my water bottle and not inside it.)*

Comment: Ammonium nitrate will do.

Comment: Maybe you have a liquid propane cylinder (or any liquified gas for that matter) , spraying the propane that is just expanded into vapour form on water bottle will be much helpful in cooling without compromising the water.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ammonium nitrate, calcium ammonium nitrate, and urea are each used in instant-cold packs. The dissolution of any of these compounds in water is an endothermic process and will thus cool your container of water.

In a practical sense, it doesn't seem likely that you would sacrifice some of your water so the rest of it could be cold in an emergency situation. Of course, the water you use for cooling does not have to be clean and potable.

Comment: any water less chemical mix ? can it make ice

Comment: +1 for the second paragraph.  I bring in water for construction crews working on the library in my work office building.  It just sits there not cooled but the guys appreciate it nonetheless.  Moral of the story:  having water is more important than having it cold.

Comment: @murmansk Regarding your waterless idea, it is unlikely that any dry compounds would produce significant cooling on mixing. It is the heat of dissolution of certain solids into water that provide the cooling for most chemical cooling packs and such. As far as using a chemical cooling mixture to get ice, that would depend on the temperature of the water to start with, how much water you want to freeze and how much of the external cooling mixture you have. It would be difficult though, as the latent heat released when freezing water is quite large. Sorry so long to get back, hope this helps.